# 'TextChannel' object is not iterable | channel check not working

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Hi I'm trying to check to see if a channel already exists instead of creating a new one each time a member sends a modmail request. The error I get is

```
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Build 1.0.2\cogs\modmail.py", line 145, in on_message
if get(modmailchannel, name=f"{message.author.name.lower()}{message.author.discriminator}"):
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\utils.py", line 271, in get
for elem in iterable:
TypeError: 'TextChannel' object is not iterable
enter code here
```

not sure why or the method is incorrect some how. The channel name that is created is the users name and discriminator. What I'm trying to achieve is if that channel already exists don't create another channel/post in the same channel.

Help appreicated

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, message):
    if not isinstance(message.channel, discord.DMChannel) or message.author.id == self.bot.user.id:
        # not a DM, or it's just the bot itself
        return
    
    bucket = self._cd.get_bucket(message)
    retry_after = bucket.update_rate_limit()
    seconds = bucket.update_rate_limit()
    seconds = round(seconds, 2)
    hours, remainder = divmod(int(seconds), 3600)
    minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)
    if retry_after:
        pass
    else:
        channel = self.bot.get_channel(744311308509249610)
        if not channel:
            print("Mail channel not found! Reconfigure bot!")
        time = datetime.utcnow()
        guild = self.bot.get_guild(715288565877309521)
        member_role = get(guild.roles, name='Members')
        mod_role = get(guild.roles, name='Members')
        muted_role = get(guild.roles, name='Modmail Muted')
        user_id = message.author.id
        author = guild.get_member(user_id)
        
        content = message.clean_content
        
        if muted_role in author.roles:
            await message.channel.send("You're not allowed to use modmail.")
            return
        
        if len(message.content) < 0:
            await message.channel.send("Your message should be atleast 50 characters in length.")
            return
    
        if member_role in author.roles:
            emoji1 = ''
            emoji2 = '️'
            message_confirm = "You're about to send a message to the mod team, react with :incoming_envelope: to confirm otherwise :wastebasket: to discard your message."
            embed = discord.Embed(description=message_confirm, colour=0x5539cc)
            embed.title = "Confirm Message"
            confirm = await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
            await confirm.add_reaction(emoji1)
            await confirm.add_reaction(emoji2)
            check = reaction_check(message=confirm, author=message.author, emoji=(emoji1, emoji2))
            try:
                reaction, user = await self.bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=60.0, check=check)
                if reaction.emoji == emoji1:
                    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Message Sent", description=f"Hello {message.author.display_name}! We have received your message and we will get back to you as soon as possible. You can send another message in **{minutes}m {seconds}s**.", timestamp=time, colour=0x5539cc)
                    await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
                elif reaction.emoji == emoji2:
                    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Message Not Sent", description=f"Your message has not been sent. You can send another message in **{minutes}m {seconds}s**.", timestamp=time, colour=0x5539cc)
                    await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
                    return
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                await message.channel.send(f'Sorry, you took too long to confirm your message. Try again in **{minutes}m {seconds}s**.')
                return
            overwrites = {
                guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
                guild.me: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True),
                member_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
                mod_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True)}
            
            embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Modmail message request from — {message.author.name}#{message.author.discriminator}", colour=0xff8100)
            embed.add_field(name="Member:", value=f"{message.author.mention}" ,inline=True)
            embed.add_field(name="Reply ID:", value=f"{message.author.id}" ,inline=True)
            embed.add_field(name="Message:", value=content[:1000] or "blank", inline=False)
            embed.set_footer(text=f"C&P Command: !reply {message.author.id}")
            if message.attachments:
                embed.add_field(name="Attachments", value=", ".join([i.url for i in message.attachments]))
            if len(content[1000:]) > 0:
                embed.add_field(name="Message (continued):", value=content[1000:])
            modmailchannel = await guild.create_text_channel(f'{message.author.name}{message.author.discriminator}', overwrites=overwrites, category=self.bot.get_channel(744944688271720518))
            await modmailchannel.send(embed=embed)
            
            if get(modmailchannel, name=f"{message.author.name.lower()}{message.author.discriminator}"):
                 await modmailchannel.send(embed=embed)
            
        else:
            await message.channel.send("Only members can use modmail.")
```

Comment: Could you provide the whole error message?

Comment: Just added full error updated in question .

Comment: Are you checking if `modmailchannel.name` is a particular value?  If so, you should just use `modmailchannel.name==...`

Comment: `modmailchannel.name==` As a check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of if `get(modmailchannel, name=f"{message.author.name.lower()}{message.author.discriminator}"):` use:

```
if modmailchannel.name == f"{message.author.name.lower()}{message.author.discriminator}":
```

Comment: Thanks I tried this but I think I need to figure out how I'm doing this. It seems to be keep on creating the channels rather that checking to see if it already exists. I must be doing something wrong here. Thanks for your answer though :)

Comment: @James where in the code do you check if the channel already exists?

Comment: I do see that it seems to be missing. *scratches head I will need to somehow make a check to see if the channel exists before creating one. Is that possible with `modmailchannel = await guild.create_text_channel(f'{message.author.name}{message.author.discriminator}', overwrites=overwrites, category=self.bot.get_channel(744944688271720518))
            await modmailchannel.send(embed=embed)` as that will always be called every time a message is sent creating duplicate channels.

Comment: @James you could integrate a simple check in the code before creating the channel `channel_present = False for channel in guild.text_channels: if channel.name == f"{message.author.name.lower()}{message.author.discriminator}": channel_present = True` Then you can check if channel_present is False then make the channel.